# Cakephp, redirecting in the routing.

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, redirect

I was wondering how to do a redirect in the routes of a cakephp application.

I simply want to redirect on url /xxx to /yyy

I don't want to have to set up a controller or and action in the pages controller just to redirect a url.

Is there a way to do it in the routing?

Cheers.

Comment: I think you can do this simply in the .htaccess file, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has now been added to cake, go can see it here:

https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/7630580511f1ece4bac3e1ea3d6f2c613de1f243

Answer (score 2):

Routes are used to *connect* URLs to controller actions. That's all they do. They do not redirect.

As @Nik suggested, if you don't want to make a controller for it, use .htaccess rules.

Comment: Well cake is based pretty heavily on rails, which does consider redirection to be part of routing. Rails has it's...

match "/xxx" => redirect("/yyy")

I assumed because there so similar cake would have one too. Routing is about dispatching a url to a controller/action, even if that url need's redirecting.

Comment: @Smickie Interesting. But Cake isn't Rails. :) You could of course hack around it, especially if using a custom URL parser class, but you probably shouldn't. What's your use case? Do you want to redirect expired URLs to new ones?

Comment: I've added a redirect to the cake roadmap, it'll be coming in a future version.

Answer (score 0):

@smickie, its *not* rails, the proper way to do it is use Controller::beforeRedirect() look it up in the api for the params that it uses.

Comment: I've added a redirect to the cake roadmap, it'll be coming in a future version.